# What is the best way to store blog content(description text, thumbnails and embedded video) in Firebase for android app?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am learning to use Firebase real time database and Firebase cloud storage for android app development. I want to create a sample app which displays the articles with description text, images and may be video.
Currently I am storing a static html page in the firebase cloud and giving that as input for firebase db. With this, I'm able to see the html page with plain text in app. However, I don't see the image content.

I am not sure what are the best ways to achieve this. Google search on this topic isn't helping much.

It would be great if I get guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Answers on this topic are awaited.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a combination of firebase firestore and firebase cloud storage. In firebase storage, you can save images, videos, files and any kind of media. And in the firestore, i would save text, description, dates, file references and etc. A plus is that you can use firebase auth and provide the users with multiple sing in options.